# MS Flow Error when adding multiple attachment to SharePoint list attachment

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, dataverse

[image]I am encountering an error message in my Power Automate workflow. The error states 'InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Add_attachment' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'base64ToBinary' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be decoded from base64 representation.' The workflow involves retrieving data from Dataverse and adding it, along with its attachment, to a SharePoint list.

It is important to note that the workflow was previously functioning correctly but has suddenly stopped working. Additionally, the workflow works fine when there is only one attachment.

I have attached an image of the workflow for reference.

Any guidance or assistance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.[image]

Comment: Too hard to help without screenshots, etc.

Comment: sorry i thought i attached

Comment: The error you mentioned is not the one in the screenshot.

Comment: And perhaps share a snip of `Add attachments 2` expanded. And did it work before with multiple attachments?

Comment: @SamNseir yes it used to work and worked few times.

Comment: @Skin will update the question and add screenshot of the requested